# OnStart - Different behavior for Global Variable between Play Mode and Edit Mode

Tags: powerapps

It's been one year since I'm using power apps and so far I succeeded in resolving all my issues but I'm now blocked on a specific one where I need support.

I managed the loading of my app for SP list and Collection building via triggering Global Variables set on a specific screen (not the screen loaded on start).
When the app is starting, OnStart is initializing my variables to trigger the refresh of SP List and collection.
It works perfectly in Edit Mode but it doesn't in Play mode. I checked on the monitor, it looks like OnStart is well triggered since I have some collection built in it and it's well done. I have set up a simple Set() variable at the end of OnStart

Also on top of that issue, I have the name of the user displayed on top of the page using Office User Library. The name is well displayed in Edit Mode but not in Play Mode.

For information, I tried to save a new version but I get the same thing.

Any idea there? Have you already experienced this issue?

Thank you
Bastien

Answer (score 0):

Check out the "on Visible" property of the screen. This one is refreshed whenever the screen is navigated to , so that should fire when the app opens and when you navigate between screens.

> OnVisible – The behavior of an app when the user navigates to a
> screen. Use this property to set up variables and preload data used by
> the screen. Use the App.OnStart property for set up once when the app
> is started.
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/controls/control-screen